# Create a new contact record when any update made on contact's Address fields

Tags: trigger, contact

I have a workflow which updates the Salesforce contact address fields like Address1,Address2,City,State and Postal Code when user edits the fields from UI.My requirement is 'When a user tries to edit these fields from UI,instead of editing those fields directly,needs to create a new contact record with the updated address information.'

I would be grateful if someone help me with this??

Comment: This can be done using Process Builder or Apex triggers. However why are you updating the same fields using workflow when user is editing the fields from the UI?

Comment: Sorry,fileds gets edited from UI,not from workflow..I am concerned about not updating the existing address field values.I know that we can create a new contact record with Apex triggers and process builder.But how to create those records without updating the existing address fields..Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to avoid updating the existing contact record and create a new record in case someone updates any of the address fields. This can be done using a simple trigger on `contact`.

Have a `before update` trigger on `Contact` where you will fetch the old values of the records from the `Trigger.old`(precisely `Trigger.oldMap`) and assign to `trigger.new`, keeping the existing records intact.

Next, catch all those contacts from trigger.new during the previous operation in a list and simply clone them and insert.

However following this approach your existing records will actually be updated, updated with previous values.

If you want to avoid this dummy update of existing records, you might consider having a VF page to take users' input.